# Using JwtBearerOption MetadataAddress with Google

Tags: firebase, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I've used Azure AD B2C successfully for my API.
Until now I obtainted the signing key by setting the `JwtBearerOptions.MetadataAddress` to `https://<mytentant>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Now I also have to support tokens issues by Google Firebase.
Google mentions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens?hl=de#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) it's metadata endpoint which returns an entirely different format than the one from Azure.
Running the Api results in a key not found error (kid not found).
Registering the key from the endpoint manually works.

Is it somehow possible to use the Google Metadata with `JwtBearerOptions.MetadataAddress` or what needs to be done to be able to use the Google Metadata endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this:
While it is not possbile to set the `JwtBearerOptions.MetadataAddress` it is possible to set `JwtBearerOptions.Authority = https://securetoken.google.com/<your-project>`

Then it will pick up the keys correctly.